# LNK2019 link against D3DCompiler problem?

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors

The two errors are:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol D3DCompileFromFile referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl GraphicsEngine::createShaders(void)" (?createShaders@GraphicsEngine@@QEAA_NXZ)   3D Graphics Engine C++ at1  C:\Users\User\Desktop\Exam\3D Graphics Engine C++ at1\3D Graphics Engine C++ at1\GraphicsEngine.obj 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  3D Graphics Engine C++ at1  C:\Users\User\Desktop\Exam\3D Graphics Engine C++ at1\x64\Debug\3D Graphics Engine C++ at1.exe  1

The second one is directly caused by the first, and this is the first time I get a linker problem so I don't have an idea how to fix it!

I've seen several problems solved here by changing the project settings but my settings were as they say to be solved, others say to change the order (what they are called or something like that) but I can't find where to do that, so I decided to write here for the help!

Comment: Are you linking with `D3DCompiler.lib` as specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3dcompiler/nf-d3dcompiler-d3dcompilefromfile)?

Comment: I think so. I think it's says the problem is here: bool GraphicsEngine::createShaders()
{
 ID3DBlob* errblob = nullptr;
 D3DCompileFromFile(L"shader.fx", nullptr, nullptr, "vsmain", "vs_5_0", NULL, NULL, &m_vsblob, &errblob);
 D3DCompileFromFile(L"shader.fx", nullptr, nullptr, "psmain", "ps_5_0", NULL, NULL, &m_psblob, &errblob);
 m_d3d_device->CreateVertexShader(m_vsblob->GetBufferPointer(), m_vsblob->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &m_vs);
 m_d3d_device->CreatePixelShader(m_psblob->GetBufferPointer(), m_psblob->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &m_ps);
 return true;
}

Comment: The important part of the error is `unresolved external symbol D3DCompileFromFile`. That function requires linking with `D3DCompiler.lib`. Did you add that as an additional library in your project configuration for the target you are compiling? An alternative would be to add `#pragma comment(lib, "D3DCompiler.lib")` to one of your cpp files.

Comment: So you mean the #include <d3dcompiler.h> then yes or am I miss understand?

Comment: Yes, including a header file and linking to a library are different things. The header file provides the declarations of the types and functions available but the library contains the actual code. It is possible to have a header only library, especially for templates, and the documentation should explain that no external library is needed in that case.

Comment: So I neеd just the in #include <d3dcompiler.h>, but it still gives the error?

Comment: No, you need to link the required library that the documentation I linked earlier shows. I also explained how to do it above.

Comment: Ok thanks but now is giving 'Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->m_vsblob was nullptr.'

Comment: That is a different problem. There is a bug in your code.